# Cannot Append new list data to a dict in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I have a list of IPs being returned from a POST in listip. I want to iterate over the list of IPs and store data in a dictionary so i can render it on a webpage. But the dictionary is overriding the values for the last IP only. How can i solve this ? Currently there are 3 IPs in the listip but dict is only storing the last passed IPs data.

```
def healthcheckresults(request):
if not listip:
    return render(request, "home/homepage.html",)
for ip in range(len(listip)):
    conn = manager.connect(
    host= listip[ip],
    port='22',
    username='XXX',
    password = 'XXX',
    timeout=10
    )
    result = conn.get_ospf_neighbor_information()
    hostnameresult = conn.get_software_information()
    hostname = hostnameresult.xpath('//software-information/host-name/text()')
    ospfneighboraddress = result.xpath('//ospf-neighbor/neighbor-address/text()')
    ospfneighborinterface = result.xpath('//ospf-neighbor/interface-name/text()')
    ospfneighborstate= result.xpath('//ospf-neighbor/ospf-neighbor-state/text()')
    ospfneighborID = result.xpath('//ospf-neighbor/neighbor-id/text()')
    
    ##METHOD1
    ospfdictkey = {"hostname":[],"ospfneighboraddress":[],"ospfneighborinterface":[],"ospfneighborstate":[],"ospfneighborID":[]}
    ospfmetalist = [hostname,ospfneighboraddress,ospfneighborinterface,ospfneighborstate,ospfneighborID]
    for key, value in zip(ospfdictkey, ospfmetalist):
        ospfdictkey[key].append(value)
        
    ##METHOD2
    ospfdict={"hostname":hostname,"ospfneighboraddress":ospfneighboraddress,"ospfneighborinterface":ospfneighborinterface, "ospfneighborstate":ospfneighborstate,"ospfneighborID":ospfneighborID }
    context = {'LUnique': zip(ospfneighboraddress, ospfneighborinterface, ospfneighborstate,ospfneighborID)}
    conn.close_session()

listip.clear()
return render(request, "healthcheck/healthcheckresults.html",{
    "ospfneighboraddress":ospfneighboraddress,
    "ospfneighborinterface":ospfneighborinterface,
    "ospfneighborstate":ospfneighborstate,
    "ospfneighborID":ospfneighborID,
    "context":context,
    "hostname":hostname,
    "listip":listip,
    "ospfdict":ospfdict,
    "ospfdictkey":ospfdictkey,
})
```

Both mentioned methods are returning the same data when i check the data in the dictionary.

{'hostname': ['R3-ISP'], 'ospfneighboraddress': ['192.168.5.34', '192.168.5.5', '192.168.5.10'], 'ospfneighborinterface': ['ae10.0', 'ae2.0', 'ae3.0'], 'ospfneighborstate': ['Full', 'Full', 'Full'], 'ospfneighborID': ['172.0.0.6', '172.0.0.2', '172.0.0.4']}

{'hostname': [['R3-ISP']], 'ospfneighboraddress': [['192.168.5.34', '192.168.5.5', '192.168.5.10']], 'ospfneighborinterface': [['ae10.0', 'ae2.0', 'ae3.0']], 'ospfneighborstate': [['Full', 'Full', 'Full']], 'ospfneighborID': [['172.0.0.6', '172.0.0.2', '172.0.0.4']]}
['R3-ISP']

Comment: return the dict

Comment: Hint: when the code for "method 1" runs, logically, *how many times* should the dict be initialized with empty lists in order for that code to work? (Think carefully about the *reason* for doing it at all, and how it helps to solve the problem.) How many times *does* it happen? (Think carefully about what loops the code is inside or outside.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. If you tried two different approaches to a problem, please show them separately, as separate pieces of code that could be run by themselves, and put the corresponding output next to each. Please format textual output like code, and try to cut each code example down to the part *that is necessary to show the problem*. For example, would you still have the problem if there were only one key-value pair that needed to be updated? Does it matter where e.g. the `ospfneighborID` comes from, or can you show the problem with a hard-coded value?

Comment: ahh I see that now, every time i run the for loop, my dict becomes empty in method1, but that's not the case in method2. What am i missing here ?

Comment: Still unable to produce all values in the dict, should i repost my question properly?.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each method you are overwriting the dict. Remember that the code is repeating in each iteration of

```
for ip in range(len(listip)):
```

Which means that when you set the keys and values in the first line of each method you are overwriting any dict of that name that has gone before.

One way to avoid this would be to create an empty list, and append each new dict to it upon creation. Then you can cycle through the list to see each dict.

```
aList = []
for ip in range(len(listip)):
...
#Method1
...
aList.append(ospfdictkey )
#Method2
...
aList.append(ospfdict)
```